# Laravel Relationship Eager Loading belongsTo incorrect

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table called books.
I have a table called scores which is based on a metric on 100.

This is the select I wish to preform:

SELECT * FROM books AS b
LEFT JOIN scores AS s
ON  s.media_type_id = 1 AND s.media_id = b.id
ORDER BY s.sorting_score

I am using Eloquent ORM only (not the full framework)

inside Book Model:

```
public function score()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Score', 'scores', 'media_id','id');
}
```

is the relationship.

```
$books = Book::with(array('score' => function($query) use ($id)
            {
               $query->where('media_type_id','=',$id)->orderBy('sorting_score','ASC');
            }))->get();
```

its not yielding the same result.

I have two questions:
Did my concept of Eager Loading is wrong?
If so - how do I do join appropriately in Laravel in order to mimic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading in `Eloquent` runs another query with `WHERE IN` clause, so probably not what you expected.

This is how you build that query:

```
$books = Book::leftJoin('scores s', 'scores.media_id', '=', 'books.id')
             ->where('s.media_type_id', '=', $typeId)
             ->orderBy('s.sorting_scores')
             ->get();
```

And by the way the relation definition is wrong. That's how it should look like:

```
// Book model
public function score()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Score', 'media_id');
      // possibly this would be necessary too:
      // ->where('media_type_id', 1); // assuming 1 for type Book 
}
```

then the other relation:

```
// Score model
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Book', 'media_id');
      // ->where('media_type_id', 1);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why the belongsTo was wrong and hasOne instead.

Comment: It's inversion of `belongsTo`. Basically when you refer on `scores` to key of the `Book`, then we could say that a `Book` has one (or many) `Score`s, so a `Score` belongs to a `Book`

Comment: But the score is the only one that has the relationship - book has no direct relationship without the score table. Will this still work?

Comment: Check the edit. I suppose this is what you need. Still, the query builder I gave you will work anyways. Also read on the polymorphic relations: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks for the edit - it explains more. I ran circle on the doc, I wish they had a translation of SQL to Eloquent more.